# Javascript Animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, animation

On a webpage we'd like to gamify it a bit - so when a user completes an action we award them coins.

Ideally we'd like to have their total coins listed at the top of the page and then have an animation where the coins shoot up and increment their total earned coins whenever they are earned. This is pretty common in many mobile games.

I know in theory I could generate a bunch of bunch of `div`s with absolute positions and then write a function somewhat like this:

```
function moveCoin() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("coinOne");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
```

But getting everything right and responsive on all device sizes doesn't sound fun. I was curious if anyone knows of any javascript / angular libraries that we could use to achieve this sort of animation?

Comment: Asking for libraries and the like is off topic, at almost 2k rep you should know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you will have to compute the ending position manually.

This is not that tough as it sounds; you can use `getBoundingBox()` to calculate where the final destination of the coin should be, and then set the coin's CSS attrs 'x' and 'y' accordingly. (Note `getBoundingBox` does a repaint, so it'd be good to consider finding the position early on and cache the result.)

I would additionally recommend that you only set the `top` and `left` once, and then use CSS animations to set the path. This will mean that you only need one Javascript interrupt instead of 300. Otherwise your animations may have pronounced lag depending on how powerful the CPU of the device is (lag that you might not notice if developing on desktop or using powerful devices).

Your coin class can have styling like:

```
{
  transition: all 2s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
```

And you can use a tool to decide what your path should look like, such as http://cubic-bezier.com.

If you do not think a cubic-bezier function is sufficient (for example you want your coins to overshoot in a certain way), you can use `keyframes` to code out where your object should be when it's 50% through, 75% through, etc. There is a pretty good guide here: http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

The interaction you are looking for is very specific, and you're unlikely to find a library for it. It can be a lot of work to get this sort of things right, but here are the basic functions you'll need to call for each animation. You can fill in their guts.

`getCoinPosition(coinEl)`

`getTotalCoinsPosition(coinEl)`

`moveTo(startPosition, endPosition, coinElement)`

I would also look into Tween.js.

#### Important Performance Consideration:

Don't animate the `position` properties, as those can't take advantager of hardware acceleration. You'll want to animate the `transform` CSS property and use `translateX()` and `translateY()` to move the coins around. It requires a little extra consideration as that property is stored as a Matrix string. There are other questions around animating the `transform` property you can look for.

Just don't expect to get a smooth animation by changing `top` and `left`.